# sass: effect another element when another div is hovered

Tags: html, sass

This question has been answered in **CSS** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered), but I haven't been able to find an answer to it in **sass**. I'm trying to effect a div inside of another div whenever the outer div is hovered.

For example:

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b">
      <p>Hello!</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

In sass, I would want to target `div b`'s `p` tag and change it to a different color whenever `div a` is hovered over. Is this possible in sass?
right now all I have is this:

```
#a{
   &:hover{
   //code to effect div b
   }
}
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found worked:

```
#a{
   //original color
   #b{
      p{
         color: red;
      }
   }

   //after hover
   &:hover{
      #b{
         p{
            color: green;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you to @HunterTurner for leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

**SASS**

```
#a {
  #b p:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/YWWRWa)

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents if someone ends up here for a *similar but not exactly the same issue*

I was trying to affect the span inside a div when `hover` applies:

```
.my-container {

  &:hover {
    color: red; // whatever
      > span {  /* the first span child */
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: blue;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parent_class {
  .child_1 {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .child_2 {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &:has(.child_2:hover) {
    .child_2 > div {
      background-color: #8B0000;
    }

    .child_1 {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
}
```